# Increase maximum line style width

Tags: qgis, symbology, units

I'm drawing lines in QGIS and need to specify the width as map units because I want the width to be the same, regardless of scale. The projection I'm using is standard in my field so I don't want to use a different.

My projection map units are meter and I'm working on continental/global scale. The lines should be 2-300km wide.

Everything works fine, except when I put a line width over 100km, QGIS changes the width down to 99999 (m) automatically. Is there any walk around that allows me to specify broader symbols for lines?

QGIS version
2.18.14

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible - just click the "data defined override" next to the size option, and select "Edit". You can then enter any value you want and it won't be subject to the maximum value constraint. See below:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, it works. Cheers!